# Reference to non-existent field 'xData'

Tags: matlab, simulink, dspace

I use a model called 'demonstration' on Simulink/dSpace made by someone else a few years ago (we use version R2009a). When I try to incremental build, this Model error appears:

> Error building Real-Time Workshop target for block diagram 'demonstration'.
>
> MATLAB error message: Error due to multiple causes: --> Reference to non-existent field 'xData'. --> Error in 'demonstration/Wind speed': Initialization commands cannot be evaluated."

Subsequently I tried to click on the signal builder block `Wind speed`, but then the following error appears:

> Error due to multiple causes:
>
> -->Reference to non-existent field 'xData'. -->Error evaluating 'OpenFcn' callback of Sigbuilder block block (mask) 'Wind speed'. Reference to non-existent field 'xData'.

Does anyone have a clue what's going wrong here? I thank you very much.

```
Block {
      BlockType           SubSystem
      Name            "Wind speed"
      Tag             "STV Subsys"
      Ports           [0, 1]
      Position            [295, 275, 370, 315]
      CopyFcn             "sigbuilder_block('copy');"
      DeleteFcn           "sigbuilder_block('delete');"
      LoadFcn             "sigbuilder_block('load');"
      ModelCloseFcn       "sigbuilder_block('modelClose');"
      PreSaveFcn          "sigbuilder_block('preSave');"
      StartFcn            "sigbuilder_block('start');"
      StopFcn             "sigbuilder_block('stop');"
      NameChangeFcn       "sigbuilder_block('namechange');"
      ClipboardFcn        "sigbuilder_block('clipboard');"
      OpenFcn             "sigbuilder_block('open',[49.5 50.25 519.75 399.75 ]);"
      CloseFcn            "sigbuilder_block('close');"
      MinAlgLoopOccurrences   off
      PropExecContextOutsideSubsystem off
      RTWSystemCode       "Auto"
      FunctionWithSeparateData off
      Opaque              off
      RequestExecContextInheritance off
      MaskHideContents        on
      MaskType            "Sigbuilder block"
      MaskInitialization      "if ~strcmp(get_param(bdroot(gcb),'SimulationStatus'),'stopped') tuvar = sigbuilder_bloc"
      "k('maskInit'); end"
      MaskDisplay         "plot(0,0,100,100,[10,10,40,40,10],[80,20,20,80,80],[40,10],[50,50], [40,27,10],[65,72,56],[40"
      ",25,25,10],[28,28,43,43]);"
      MaskIconFrame       on
      MaskIconOpaque          off
      MaskIconRotate          "port"
      MaskPortRotate          "default"
      MaskIconUnits       "autoscale"
      Port {
    PortNumber      1
    Name            "Vvent"
    RTWStorageClass     "Auto"
    DataLoggingNameMode "SignalName"
      }
      System {
    Name            "Wind speed"
    Location        [480, 93, 1016, 386]
    Open            off
    ModelBrowserVisibility  off
    ModelBrowserWidth   200
    ScreenColor     "white"
    PaperOrientation    "landscape"
    PaperPositionMode   "auto"
    PaperType       "A4"
    PaperUnits      "centimeters"
    TiledPaperMargins   [1.270000, 1.270000, 1.270000, 1.270000]
    TiledPageScale      1
    ShowPageBoundaries  off
    ZoomFactor      "100"
    Block {
      BlockType       Demux
      Name            "Demux"
      Tag             "STV Demux"
      Ports           [1, 1]
      Position        [150, 15, 160, 35]
      Outputs         "1"
    }
    Block {
      BlockType       FromWorkspace
      Name            "FromWs"
      Tag             "STV FromWs"
      Position        [30, 300, 115, 350]
      VariableName        "tuvar"
      SampleTime          "0"
      SigBuilderData      "DataTag0"
      VnvData         "DataTag1"
    }
    Block {
      BlockType       Outport
      Name            "Signal 1"
      Tag             "STV Outport"
      Position        [250, 20, 270, 30]
      IconDisplay         "Port number"
    }
    Line {
      SrcBlock        "Demux"
      SrcPort         1
      DstBlock        "Signal 1"
      DstPort         1
    }
    Line {
      SrcBlock        "FromWs"
      SrcPort         1
      DstBlock        "Demux"
      DstPort         1
    }
      }
    }
```

Comment: `xData` doesn't exist. Pretty hard to say anything beyond that without a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). How about `XData`?

Comment: Are you certain the model was made in the same MATLAB version as that program is? Also: R2009a is by now 7 years old, might want to update that.

Comment: @excaza That's what the error says, but what and how could I do something about that? And this is probably a stupid question, but it the error sends me to the simulink model, the actual drawing, how can I get to the code of it?

Comment: @Adriaan I'm pretty sure of that, and yes it is, however I tried in the 2015 version, but that didn't work out, so I stuck with the 2009 version, since I'm not too good with Matlab.

Comment: @excaza it seems to be 'xData' [link](http://imgur.com/noxv0g1)

Comment: @ArtFi: Open the mask for the signal builder block. My guess is that it is referring some workspace variables wich don't exist.

Comment: @Daniel By 'Open the mask' do you mean 'Mask Parameters'? In that case, apparently it isn't possible, as you can see: [link](http://imgur.com/Tpr8Whj)

Comment: Double click a block to open the mask

Comment: @Daniel That doesn't go either, than I get this error: [link](http://imgur.com/noxv0g1)

Comment: Something is really wrong with that signal builder block. I suspect it got destroyed by a sequence of updating to new simulink versions and downgrading it back again.

Comment: Hi, I found a doc with some code (this is the code for the problem causing block 'Wind speed'), is it this kind of code that you meant? Strange enough there is no trace of 'xData'. I copied the code in my question

Comment: I don't see any connection between the trc file you pasted and the error. Reading the question again, it seems there is also no connection between the dSPACE Software and your error, from what I understand it already exists with the individual Simulink block. Try to create a [mvce] and make it available to us, not only screenshots. Make sure not to use any dSPACE blocksets in that example. It might be that just pasting the Singnal Builder into a new model is enough to create such an example.

Comment: @Daniel That didn't make much sense indeed, and I don't think as well that dSPACE has a lot to do with it, I just said that to be clear about the situation. I now copied a part of -what I think is- the 'real' code, does this count as a mvce?

Comment: Ah messed up the link swapping characters, I wanted to write `[mcve]` which automatically gets replaced with this link: [mcve]. Something we could run would be necessary to understand it. The code above does not look like a complete model.

Comment: @Daniel I made the same mistake, I had already read what [mcve] is, I just didn't know if the above code met those conditions. Like you said, I now pasted the signal block, and I copied the code (It's complete and verifiable, but not too minimal, is it ok though?)

Comment: No, because I can not run it. Some minimal model only containing that block would be required.

Comment: @Daniel Yes, I'm sorry I tried to edit it, but didn't see that it didn't work, because it contains 38648 characters while the body is limited to 30000. I really don't know how I could possibly make it shorter, is there another solution you propose? (I'm very sorry for my poor set of skills)

Comment: Upload the model somewhere, Dropbox, Google Drive or similar.

Comment: @Daniel https://docs.google.com/document/d/124BCZbFqGhAwtXZrAf_l8h1US9lL_BUdXSBr9SysD_4/edit?usp=sharing
I think this should do it, thank you very much already

Answer (score 0):

The problem is what I expected it to be in my comment some days ago

> Something is really wrong with that signal builder block. I suspect it got destroyed by a sequence of updating to new simulink versions and downgrading it back again.

Running the model in a more recent version it runs without an error. Also knowing that most dSPACE RTI blocks don't support downgrading at all, you probably have to recreate the full model.

Comment: Thank you very much. What do you mean by "don't support downgrading at all", when I tried to open it in R2015a, there were indeed problems with the dSPACE RTI blocks, but isn't this an upgrading problem? And do you mean recreate the full model in a recent version? (Because then the next problem would be: what to do with those RTI blocks)

Comment: Once being downgraded even an upgrade back to the original version does not fix the problems with RTI. Never use the export to old version when using RTI.

Comment: Sorry I'm afraid I don't understand you very well, what you mean by "Never use the export to old version", and what would you propose to do now?

Comment: Unfortunately, throw away the model and create it new from scratch. The model is already destroyed, it is useless.

Comment: That's nearly impossible :( It's a huge model and very complex, in fact it was someone's doctorate to make that model, so he worked years on it. I just have to use it, or that's what should have been the intention, if it weren't for this error

Comment: Then try to get access to an old version which does not have the problem. I understand that this is bad news, but the model as it is is practically not usable.

Comment: I'm afraid there are no older versions, and rebuilding the model is no option, so now I'm truly desperate :). However, I must thank you very very much for your time and effort! I'm still miles away from a solution, but I'm a  little closer though.

Comment: Maybe you would want to know: I created a new signal block in the R2009a version and I drew the same signal as we saw in R2015a. The code has slightly changed in a few ways, but for the time being it seems to work.

Comment: For verification upgrade the old model to 2015a, put both signal blocks into one model and compare.

Comment: How do you update a model to a newer version of MATLAB (or is that just opening it in R2015a?)? And sorry I don't understand exactly what you mean, should I only update the signal block, and how should I compare them? (You do know I'm still working in R2009a version?)

Comment: Open the model in 2015a, copy the signal block next to the reference and compare both outputs (Plot and equal operator).